# surrounding layer not covered all the box as designed and there is an extra white space in the left side of the button?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to follow to code javascript and trying to code a website like this website [sample link](https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/tryw3css_templates_band.htm#)

I just want to code the Home, Bane, Tour, Contact and More button. And my problem is, as you can see in this picture, [image: picture about my problem]

When I click to button More, it show button Mechandise, Extras, Media, but the background color not covered all the box as the designed.

Here is my code, styles.css file

```
{
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
box-sizing: border-box;
}
html {
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
#main
#header {
background-color: #000;
height: 46px;
}
#nav, .subnav {
list-style-type: none;
top:100%;
left: 0;
}
#nav .subnav a {
color: #000 ;
padding: 0 16px;
}
#nav > li {
display: inline-block;
}
#nav > li > a {
color: #fff;
text-transform: uppercase;
}
#nav li a {
text-decoration: none;
line-height: 46px;
padding: 0 24px;
display: block;
}
#nav  li {
display: inline-block;
position:relative
}
#nav > li:hover > a {
color: #000;
background-color: #ccc;
display: inline-block;
}
#nav .subnav li:hover a
{
color: #000;
background-color: #ccc;
}
#nav .subnav {
display: none;
position: absolute;
background-color: #fff;
}
#nav li:hover .subnav {
display: block;
}
#slider {
min-height: 600px;
background-color: #333;
}
#content
#footer
```

I am a newbie with html css, so please explain detailed for me. Thank you very much for your time.

@BillJustin : here is my html code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>Document</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./assets/css/styles.css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="main">
<div id="header">
       <ul class="" id="nav">
            <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Band</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Tour</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
            <li>
                <a href="">More</a>
                <ul class="subnav">
                    <li><a href="">Merchandise</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Extras</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Media</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="slider">
    </div>
    <div id="content">
    </div>
    <div id="footer">
    </div>
    </div>
    </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: can you also include your html code?

Answer (score 0):

It is because of display inline block you set on anchor tags and list items. Just remove display inline block from these two rules.

```
#nav > li:hover > a {
color: #000;
background-color: #ccc;
//display: inline-block;
display: block;

}
#nav  li {
//display: inline-block;
position:relative
}
```

As [mozilla document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display) mentioned:

> inline-block
> The element generates a block element box that will be flowed with surrounding content as if it were a single inline box (behaving much like a replaced element would).